# Core Data : "insertNewObjectForEntityForName" question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to use "insertNewObjectForEntityForName", but I've got a problem with my declaration, I wondered if someone had an opinion on this .

This is my implementation :

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

// Create Object
Shots *newShot = (Shots *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Shots" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

It's complaining that "Shots" is undeclared, now my question is : Do I need to declare a new class for Shots ? Knowing that it appears as a NSManagedObject in the dataModeler ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to write your own "Shots" class. In which case, use "NSManagedObject" as the data type instead. It'll respond to accessing the Shots data fields.

```
NSManagedObject *newShot = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Shots" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

You *can* write a Shots class, it will have NSManagedObject as its base class, if you need to implement model behavior particular to the Shots objects.

Answer (score 2):

Have you included `#import "Shots.h`" at the top of this file?

I am not sure what you mean by "undeclared", but an NSManagedObject (Core Data Entity) is just like any other object; if you want to use it, you need to import it.

Comment: Ok, you are right I should reformulate, let me edit the question

Answer (score 0):

you will also probably need to click on your shots entity in the datamodule and then click file->new and you will be presented with a new item called "managed Object class" once you u go through the steps it will write down that class as you made the entity in the dataModule.